# Games are very choppy with low FPS

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games, steam, nvidia-geforce

I've just installed Ubuntu and I am trying to get into gaming with it.

I have a problem that all my games are very choppy with low FPS. I'm not sure if it's using my Nvidia GeForce 1050 .

I have set up Steam Play. I've installed and tried Left 4 Dead 2,  American Truck Sim, GMod, and Euro Truck Sim and they all have low FPS. I also tried to run Monster Hunter World which is Windows only. I tried to get it to work with proton but it wouldn't even launch so I didn't bother with it any further.

When I open "Software & Updates > Additional Drivers" it shows:

NVIDIA Corporation: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] This device is using a manually-installed driver. Then it lists a bunch of things that start with "Using Nvidia driver" or "using Nvidia server". None of them are highlighted, the only option at the bottom that is selected  says "Continue using a manually installed driver".

I see beside each option is "(proprietary, tested)" or just "(proprietary)" for the Nvidia drivers, and they're all greyed out. The only thing that mentions manually installed is "Continue using a manually installed driver" which is the only option I have the ability to select.

What should I do?

Fixed! Thank you everyone for your help. I'm a little dumb and didn't realized that the drivers being greyed out meant I didn't have them!

Comment: You should install Nvidia drivers if you didn't select that option during the Ubuntu installation. Open Software & Updates > Additional drivers.

Comment: @Nautilus One of them should show "recommended" - "Manually installed" means you've installed the drivers yourself manually independent of the versions packaged against the kernel and such, which suggests that you might not have proper drivers.

Comment: @ThomasWard all I see beside each option is "(proprietary, tested)" or just "(proprietary)" for the nvidia drivers, and they're all greyed out. And the only thing that mentions manually installed is "Continue using a manually installed driver" which is the only option i have the ability to select. If I'm understanding what you said that must mean I don't have the right drivers? how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @Nmath Left 4 Dead 2, Monster hunter world (which is windows only, tried to get it to work with proton but it wouldn't even launch so I didn't bother with it), gmod, American truck sim, Euro truck sim. thats all I have downloaded for now and all of them had a low FPS, I'd assume about 7 or 10 fps.

Comment: @Nautilus Use one of the propreitary tested drivers instead of your manually installed ones.  That will help you get a good driver on your system.  Keep in mind though that **most** applications don't have Steam Play support (and GMod has a native LInux version nowadays so there's not any 'overhead' there, other than your drivers).

Comment: @ThomasWard How do I select one of those drivers? Every single option except "continue using manually installed driver" is greyed out.

Comment: @ThomasWard I figured it out, thanks for your help, it turns out I didn't have them installed, I thought the fact they were greyed out meant that something was stopping me from selecting them. (which technically there was), I just had to install them, ran a few commands in the terminal and now my games are running like perfect :)

Comment: @Nautilus Good to hear!  I posted an answer that is basically what the comment summed up - please mark it as accepted to the question is marked as solved.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using drivers that were tested and confirmed functional on your system.  Somehow, you have older drivers that were manually installed, which probably are NOT the proper drivers for your system.

Install the relevant driver packages from the system (you might have to figure out which package names you need from the output in the drivers lists yourself), install them via `apt` on the command line, then select the proprietary tested drivers.  That should improve your GPU performance a ton, rather than using 'manually installed drivers' which we can't vet.